# If electrons are magnets do they attract each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons

It is said every electron is negatively charged and so they repel each other but if electrons are tiny magnets(which are responsible for atomic attraction and how solid magnet works) does it mean opposite electron poles attract each other?

Comment: "electrons are tiny magnets"...What? Electrons *are* responsible for magnetism of materials, yes, but saying that they are *tiny magnets* is totally missing the point (and explaining nothing).

Comment: @hgfhgf Are you perhaps thinking of magnetic moments?

Comment: @ACuriousMind wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Explanation Origin of magnetism "One of the fundamental properties of an electron (besides that it carries charge) is that it has a magnetic dipole moment, i.e., it behaves itself as a tiny magnet"

Comment: @hgfhgf Follow the links on the page to learn more about magnetic moments in general.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic interaction among the electrons is very weak. The electrostatic interaction among the electrons lead to Hund's coupling among the electrons which in turn results in magnetic arrangement of these tiny magnets and magnetism of the whole solid.